# Getting LLVM/Clang to be 16 bit aligned

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, llvm

I am working on a legacy project that has a large amount of files dating back to pre-OS X days.  It's data has been 16 bit aligned for > 15 years.  I would like to move to a full LLVM compilation but I can't seem to get 2 byte alignment working.  Are there any compiler level options available for this?  (previously using -malign-mac68k)

I am aware of the #pragma pack(2) option here. However that would require me to modify upwards of 1000 source files to include this. That it's a worst-case option, but it seems like a hack. Besides, if this is possible then surely there is a default option to set the alignment?

Comment: are you using clang or llvm-gcc?  I had much better luck with clang than llvm-gcc for 32 bit alignment on a 32 bit target when compiling on a 64 bit host. (-m32 or whatever it is, is ignored by llvm-gcc).  Basically I recommend trying clang.

Comment: llvm-gcc seems to honor -malign-mac68k, so that's what we will use if there is no other solution.  I do expect llvm-gcc to be going away at some point and would prefer to fully convert if possible.  But that may have to wait if we can't find a solution.

Comment: That's a great and tricky question. You could try to ask in the LLVM IRC chat. If it's not possible, they'll probably tell you. http://llvm.org/docs/#irc

Comment: thanks for the tip gcamp, I'll ask in IRC over there.

Comment: Just curious: Why does the alignment matter?

Comment: Eiko - The data that is saved both to disk and to our database is 2 byte aligned.  This means that if I am compiling 32 bit and have an int, a char and an int variables respectively in a struct (in that order) then the first int will take 4 bytes, the character will be padded to 4 bytes, and the next int will take 4 bytes, for a sizeof() of 12 bytes.  Essentially in 32 bit your variables are on 4 byte boundaries, in 16 bit they are on 2 byte boundaries. So the code can compile 32 bit but reading existing data will be problematic as the boundaries won't be correct in our structs.  hth

Comment: Maybe it is feasible to only adjust the reading/writing routines - easy if in one spot, difficult and dangerous if spread over the code. I agree - a simple compiler switch would be convenient and push that modification into the future. Depending on memory layout looks like a time bomb, though.

Comment: Yep, spread over many places in the code.  Otherwise I'd just fix it.  If it were my personal project, I'd probably have fixed this already, but I'm not making the priorities, my boss is.  So making do with what I have.  there is a possible database migration in the future (within a few years) so if we can put it off until then this may just magically go away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to clang's sources, it does support mac68k alignment rules. It seems that right now you can enable it via "#pragma options align=mac68k" only. If you're ok with small clang hacking, then you can implement the cmdline option as well and submit the patch to clang.

Comment: That's both encouraging and discouraging.  Thanks for the heads up!  Modifying this may be beyond me (with the time I have available for this), so any volounteers to help would be wonderful.  =)

Comment: I might try if I'll find some time tonight.

Comment: Well, even if this doesn't happen by someone here I've filed a bug report with apple so hopefully this will be supported in the future.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: This will likely not be done by apple.  I recently got the apple bug report removed as an issue that their development team is aware of.  Which likely means it won't get completed by their team.  :(

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at `#pragma pack` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html).  It's relatively easy to use, and should work with any compiler Apple ships.

Comment: I am aware of the #pragma pack(2) option here.  However that would require me to modify upwards of 1000 source files to include this.  You're correct in that it's an option, but it seems like a hack.  Besides, if this is possible then surely there is a default option to set the alignment?

Comment: You could "-include" a file with "#pragma pack(2)", I guess... you don't want to be applying it to system headers, though.

Answer (score 0):

i use the latest gcc/gortran on osx compiled by the guys at ibm, if you read the gcc manual there are at least 8 different alignment optimizations to consider not just the bulk malign

Answer (score -1):

Because system-level headers assume default alignment (they don't have directives to override alignment in most cases), changing the alignment for everything will break OS calls. As such, you don't want to be doing this.

Just write a script to apply your `#pragma pack(2)` to the source files in question, avoiding `#include`s. It's relatively easy and unlikely to cause unfortunate side-effects.

Comment: I'm not sure this is completely accurate, or I'm misunderstanding you.  Currently with GCC we are compiling our code with the -malign-mac68k setting, which means anything in the project is compiled as 2 byte aligned.  It links just great with system stuff and there are no issues there currently, I don't think a setting at the LLVM level will change this -- we're already doing it with GCC this way.

Comment: @slycrel: It might work for the calls you happen to be using, but it's still a bad idea, particularly if you use other third party libraries that might not have explicit packing directives

Comment: I'd be interested as to why you think this is a "bad idea".  As I've said, this program has done any number of system calls since MacOS 6.x until today with no issues on 2 byte alignment (other than our own dumb mistakes).  You'll have to forgive me for being a bit skeptical, but I'm willing to listen.  It's not ideal for a non-standard alignment sure, but I can't see anything particularly incorrect going on here.  Other than being careful about reading and writing blocks of memory to/from disk (or between memory structs) on self-defined structures I don't see this as being an issue.

Comment: If you use an external library that has a `struct foo { short x; int y; }`, the layout of `foo` will differ between the library and your program, potentially leading to crashes or other issues. You may have been lucky enough to avoid such problems so far, but there is no guarantee you won't run into them in the future. That's why I suggest you add `#pragma pack(2)` to your own code only, to avoid problems in the future.

Comment: Yep, we're aware of those types of issues and it's business as usual dealing with them.  Really it only matters if you're doing block memory operations or writing to disk.  Member field access doesn't particularly change.  But I think you're missing the fact that #pragma pack(2) and -malign-mac68k do the same things, just that one is explicit in the code and the other is a flag when compiling the code.  The idea is to get the compiler level flag (if one exists).  I think there may be something since there are flags for 32 and 64 bit alignment.  It's an obscure request, thus the bounty.

Comment: Right, my point is to only apply it to your own headers, not `<somesystemlibrary.h>` which isn't expecting it