# Struct Byte Alignment Issue XCode 4.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, struct, alignment

I'm trying to use struct to map header of a BitMap file. It seems that compiler is doing 4byte (32bit) alignment but I need 2Byte. I tried to change that via complier directive as below

```
#pragma pack(2)
```

and

```
__attribute__ ((aligned(xx)));
```

those two doesn't seem to have any effect. Is there another way to do this? 
I'm using XCode 4.3 on Mac OS X Lion. I Tested both Apple LLVM and Apple GCC compliers.

Here is the Struct type definition

```
typedef struct {
    int16_t bfType; 
    int32_t bfSize;
    int16_t bfReserved1;
    int16_t bfReserved2;
    int32_t bfOffBits;
    int32_t biSize;
    int32_t biWidth;
    int32_t biHeight;
    int16_t biPlanes;
    int16_t biBitCount;
    int32_t biComression;
    int32_t biSizeImage;
    int32_t biXPelsPerMeter;
    int32_t biYPelsPerMeter;
    int32_t biClrUsed;
    int32_t biClrImportant;
} THeader;
```

Comment: chars are 1-byte aligned, int16 and 32 arent.  Long double is 16 byte aligned in GCC.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430214/getting-llvm-clang-to-be-16-bit-aligned

Comment: @nhahtdh That doesn't worked. Actually Compile ignores are those things.

Comment: @CodaFi, the complier is some how optimizing the struct. two 16bits will mapped to a 32bit memory. but when I have a 16bit followed by a 32bit, the 32bit will mapped to the next block!!!!! I can't imagine why xcode doing so (Actually LLVM or GCC)

Comment: @Mojtaba: The compiler does word alignment.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I see, how can I turn that off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh? works on my machine? Bear in mind that the pack pragma is possibly being overridden somewhere else?

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#pragma pack(push,2)

typedef struct {
int16_t bfType; 
int32_t bfSize;
int16_t bfReserved1;
int16_t bfReserved2;
int32_t bfOffBits;
int32_t biSize;
int32_t biWidth;
int32_t biHeight;
int16_t biPlanes;
int16_t biBitCount;
int32_t biComression;
int32_t biSizeImage;
int32_t biXPelsPerMeter;
int32_t biYPelsPerMeter;
int32_t biClrUsed;
int32_t biClrImportant;
} THeader;

#pragma pack(pop)

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
printf("%lu\n", offsetof(THeader, bfType));
printf("%lu\n", offsetof(THeader, bfSize));
printf("%lu\n", offsetof(THeader, bfReserved1));
printf("%lu\n", offsetof(THeader, bfReserved2));
return 0;
}


$ clang -o pack pack.c
$ ./pack
0
2
6
8
```

Comment: Which complier are you using? Did you try that on Cocoa Project?

Comment: This was a simple command line tool app - compiled using clang (AKA apple default compiler). Built a simple Cocoa app for Mac OSX and it did exactly the same thing. You should really do: `#pragma pack(push,2)` at the start of the definition and `#pragma pack(pop)` at the end of the declaration to ensure that the packing logic doesn't leak elsewhere.