# Using NSOutputStream, i'm seeing 00 00 0a 00 instead of 0a 00 00 00

Tags: ios, c

I'm pretty sure this isn't little/big-endian related, because my machine is little-endian (mac) and the code would deal with it anyways...

I'm writing a uint32_t to `NSOutputStream`. The code that is setting it is like this:

```
uint32_t transaction_id = 0x000A;
```

Using wireshark, I see this is transmitted as the byte sequence `00 00 0A 00`.
Correct (what the device expects) is `0A 00 00 00`

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

EDIT: I got in trouble for not including the code. Here it is. Hopefully i'm "on-topic now"

```
struct _PTPParams {
/* data layer byteorder */
uint8_t byteorder;

(snip!)    
/* ptp transaction ID */
uint32_t transaction_id;
```

...

```
params->transaction_id = htod32(0x000A); // start the transaction ID at non-zero
ret = ptp_getdeviceinfo(params,&params->deviceinfo);
```

...

```
uint16_t
ptp_getdeviceinfo (PTPParams* params, PTPDeviceInfo* deviceinfo)
{
uint16_t ret;
PTPContainer ptp;
char* di=NULL;

ptp_debug(params,"PTP: Obtaining DeviceInfo");

PTP_CNT_INIT(ptp);
ptp.Code=PTP_OC_GetDeviceInfo;
ptp.Nparam=0;
ret=ptp_transaction(params, &ptp, PTP_DP_GETDATA, 0, &di);
```

...

```
static uint16_t
ptp_transaction (PTPParams* params, PTPContainer* ptp,
             uint16_t flags, unsigned int sendlen, char** data)
{
if ((params==NULL) || (ptp==NULL))
    return PTP_ERROR_BADPARAM;

ptp->Transaction_ID=params->transaction_id++;
ptp->SessionID=params->session_id;
/* send request */
CHECK_PTP_RC(params->sendreq_func (params, ptp));
```

...

```
static uint16_t
ptpip_sendreq (PTPParams* params, PTPContainer* req)
{
static uint16_t ret;
static PTP_IP_Packet_COMMAND_REQ ptpipreq;

PTP_CNT_INIT(ptpipreq);
/* build ptp/ip container */

int32_t packetSize = PTP_IP_PacketLength_COMMAND_REQ-
(sizeof(uint32_t)*(5-req->Nparam));

ptpipreq.ptpIPPacketLength=htod32(packetSize);
ptpipreq.ptpIPType=htod32(PTP_IP_TYPE_COMMAND_REQ);
ptpipreq.ptpIPdataphase=htod32(PTP_IP_CONST_DATAPHASE);
ptpipreq.code=htod16(req->Code);
ptpipreq.trans_id=htod32(req->Transaction_ID);
/* send it */
ret=params->write_func((unsigned char *)&ptpipreq,
                       packetSize,
                       params->data);
```

...

```
static short
ptpip_write_func (unsigned char *bytes, unsigned int size, void *data)
{    
PTPCamera* cam = (__bridge PTPCamera*)data;

unsigned int bytesToWrite = size;

while( bytesToWrite > 0) {

    unsigned chunkSize = (bytesToWrite > PTP_IP_MAX_PACKET_LEN)?PTP_IP_MAX_PACKET_LEN:bytesToWrite;
    unsigned char chunk[chunkSize];
    memcpy(chunk, bytes+(size-bytesToWrite), chunkSize);

    // cam.outStream is an NSOutputStream, with NSStreamStatus = open
    int result = [cam.outStream write:chunk maxLength:chunkSize];
```

Now the packet is sent, and wireshark shows it as (PTP part only shown):

```
0000   12 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 10 00 00  ................
0010   0a 00                                            ..
```

... those last 4 bytes are the problem (transaction_id) -- should be 0A 00 00 00

EDIT 2: please note, htod16() and htod32() effectively resolve as nothing (since they are compiled on a little-endian system), so you can ignore them...

EDIT 3: **found the problem** and it's not endian-related, but don't know how to fix it. If I set the transaction_id to 0xFAFBFCFD, I see this...

[image: one]
[image: two]

... what's wrong is that there are 2 extra 00s between ptp.code (01 10) and start of transaction_id (FD).  ptp.code is a uint16_t (sizeof reports 2), so why are there 6 00s instead of 4?!

Comment: You'll need to show more code, how do you write it to the output stream?

Comment: You're "pretty sure" that a classic symptom of endianness issues/misunderstanding isn't related to endianness... how exactly?

Comment: You need to show us the code that serializes your data, and show us the full wireshark dump of the packet.

Comment: You're obviously converting the `transaction_id` to a `short` somewhere, but that line of code is not shown in your question.

Comment: Added code as requested.

Comment: This is very likely endian related. What are the platforms you're communicating between?

Comment: Code is compiled on Mac OS, runs on iPad

Comment: Probably struct padding.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It was memory alignment - from thread [Struct Byte Alignment Issue XCode 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731217/struct-byte-alignment-issue-xcode-4-3) , I used

```
#pragma pack(push,2)
```

... and now it works perfectly.